# unix timestamp value is getting converted to a scientific format while reading it using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read a csv file which has few columns. Some of the columns contains long digits as shown below. Pandas is converting these values into scientific notation.

```
"85405355309256431514161802018284625587","1","1580459391475",1
```

If I open the csv using Excel also, they get converted to scientific notation. Is there a way to prevent this and load the data as it is in CSV without converting the values?

Comment: Its not a conversion, is just how the number is displayed.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I want to see the number as it is in pandas data frame as well. However it shows something like 1.580456e+12. For some weird reason, the first column is being shown as it is but only 3rd column gets converted. Is there a way to handle this properly?

Comment: How exactly are you displaying the values? Add code please